# Localhost XAMPP 5.6.3-0 throws 403 (Forbidden) for images

Tags: apache, xampp

I recently changed my LAMP-stack to XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS to develop website locally.

I can access the XAMPP configuration page, phpMyAdmin, as well as the indiviual website projects wich are stored in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

The problem is that when I am working on a project and I use images, these images cannot be accessed in the browser. For example for a slideshow, I get the following errors:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
 - http://localhost/project/public/assets/img/image01.jpg 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
     - http://localhost/project/public/assets/img/image02.jpg
```

I assume there is a configuration problem in `httpd.conf`, which is located in `/opt/lampp/apache2/conf` and currently contains the following:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also tried to restart the server several times, without success. Access to images remains forbidden.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What does the error log file say? There must be a reason why that denial occurs.

Comment: Error log says: `[Sun Jan 25 15:13:11.124122 2015] [core:error] [pid 24700] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:59335] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/public/assets/img/image01.png, referer: http://localhost/project/`

Comment: OK! Sounds pretty straight forward to me: "file permissions deny server access". So the file permissions (inside the file system) deny access by the server (the http server). This should be all the information required to solve this.

Comment: what are file permissions of directory `img/` and file `image01.jpg`? are they world readable?

Answer (score 5):

For me worked fine, when I have changed permission to folders (e.g. I had js subfolder) as following:

```
chmod -R 755 name-of-the-folder
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: I knew your answer would work, I was finding your particular answer all over the net as I was missing just "-R" Nice one vote up++

Comment: how ot do this in windows?